# U-SQL Dynamic External Data Source

Tags: datasource, u-sql

Greetings fellow developers!

Does anyone know if there is there a way to query from dynamic external data source names in U-SQL?

For example, in the MS sample script below, we would like the "MyAzureSQLDWDataSource" to be generated dynamically.

```
@results =
    SELECT DateTime.Now AS dayTime, * 
    FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDWDataSource LOCATION "dbo.AdventureWorksDWBuildVersion";

OUTPUT @results
TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/DDL/DataSources/Query2B.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cant connect to external data source.
You can use DataFactory and use a Copy Activity to download your data to DataLake and U-SQL Activity to execute your USQL Script.
You can trigger it on demand or schedule it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already have the external data source set up and every things runs correctly. My question is on if there's a way to dynamically generate the external data source name in the U-SQL script.

Comment: If you use Data Factory you can set parameters that can be passed to U-SQL job.

Comment: I am familiar with that. However you can't use string literals for external data source identifiers. That's the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: Have you explored the ARM templates yet?